# div's height = its width, in percentages, so that the div looks like a square, with non-square shape of the container element (CSS only)

Tags: html, css

I have set my elements' widths and heights in percentages so that they look a little bigger on bigger screens and normal on normal ones. I have also set `min-height` and `min-width` so that the layout isn't distorted when viewing on a screen too small. I want one of my elements to appear as a square, but I am unable to come up with a CSS-only solution for it to happen.

Here is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/5VTTD/, but it didn't work.

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/5VTTD/1/, but it uses JS.

Comment: You have to set an explicit height to the container or the box inside derives it's height from the content of the container not the container itself, since your container isn't square and doesn't have an explicit height or width the js solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need an external `<div>` as a container and then an internal one as a square.

I used 50% dimensions for the square, but you can use the size you desire: it will be relative to the parent `<div>` container.

I also gave it a black background color to highlights it: here there is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wwvcH/).

The trick is all in the `padding-bottom: 100%` of the parent `<div>`.

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="square">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but fails if container element itself isn't a square : http://jsfiddle.net/wwvcH/3/

Comment: It fails because it's based on the parent container dimensions.

Comment: Applying a 500 and 1500 as min dimensions to the parent container make it appear as a rectangle.

Comment: This is an amazing solution if the div is a square. It is 100% responsive and works perfectly with bootstrap and transitions. Good answer considering the question asked specifically about squares.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/5VTTD/9/